# MySQL - Sorry an unexpected error happened

Tags: mysql

i'm creating a trigger that save a history when it is deleted from the student table, but when i execute the trigger code to create it, i got the error message "Sorry an unexpected error happened!" and y literally don't know what to do.

Student Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `IDstudent` varchar(5) COLLATE utf32_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Names` varchar(40) COLLATE utf32_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `SecNames` varchar(40) COLLATE utf32_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32 COLLATE=utf32_spanish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `Student`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`IDstudent`);
COMMIT;
```

Deleted Students table:

```
CREATE TABLE `DeletedStudents` (
  `IDstudent ` varchar(5) COLLATE utf32_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Names ` varchar(30) COLLATE utf32_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `SecNames ` varchar(30) COLLATE utf32_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `DateDeleted` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32 COLLATE=utf32_spanish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `DeletedStudents`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`IDstudent`);

ALTER TABLE `DeletedStudents`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `DeletedStudents_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`IDstudent`) 
REFERENCES `Student` (`IDstudent`);
COMMIT;
```

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER
\\
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Delete_Student AFTER DELETE
ON
Student FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DeletedStudents(
    IDstudent,
    Names,
    SecNames,
    DateDeleted
)
VALUES(
old.IDstudent,
old.Names,
old.SecNames,
NOW()) ;
END \\
DELIMITER
;
```

Comment: When you execute what code?

Comment: The trigger code, sorry i didn't specify

Comment: Is this while creating the trigger or while using it?

Comment: while i'm creating it

Comment: You have a bunch of mismatched table and column names. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry men, I already corrected it

Comment: `Sorry an unexpected error happened!` is not an error that is coming from MySQL.

Comment: Thanks bro, the error was in the delimiter

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I came to know that MySql gets our input as a raw string and it later parses it into sql syntax (at the backend), so using `DELIMITER \\` might create an escape character in the raw string input provided therefore throwing an error "Sorry an unexpected error happened!" which is of course an error from the parser (I mean not MySql). So the solution is to use anything other than `\\` as `DELIMITER`.